# Minikube install in Ubuntu - Something went wrong running an SSH command

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ubuntu-14.04, kubernetes, minikube

I'm going to install minikube in my Ubuntu VM (in VMWare). I first installed Virtual box inside the VM and installed kubectl and Minikube. When I run `minikube start --iso-url="https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/minikube-0.5.iso" --v=7`,
I get following error message

```
(minikube) DBG | About to run SSH command:
(minikube) DBG | exit 0
(minikube) DBG | SSH cmd err, output: exit status 255: 
(minikube) DBG | Error getting ssh command 'exit 0' : Something went wrong running an SSH command!
(minikube) DBG | command : exit 0
(minikube) DBG | err     : exit status 255
(minikube) DBG | output  : 
(minikube) DBG | 
(minikube) DBG | Getting to WaitForSSH function...
(minikube) DBG | Using SSH client type: external
(minikube) DBG | Using SSH private key: /root/.minikube/machines/minikube/id_rsa (-rw-------)
(minikube) DBG | &{[-F /dev/null -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o LogLevel=quiet -o ConnectionAttempts=3 -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlMaster=no -o ControlPath=none docker@127.0.0.1 -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -i /root/.minikube/machines/minikube/id_rsa -p 45038] /usr/bin/ssh <nil>}
```

How can i fixed this and get the minikube started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be multiple problems here:

- If the minikube is up and ssh is not working for some reason.

  To check this see if the minikube shows up in virtual box console if it shows that minikube is running then something wrong with ssh.
- If virtual box console does not show minikube is running then see in your host machine if you have enabled **nested virtualization**, if not enable it there.